Angular ng serve throws application bundle fail, unexpected end of file in JSON
I'm using the latest versions of Json and Angular, uninstalled/ reinstalled both, uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code and read every relevant reference on here and source forge.
The Angular project builds, then it throws this error 4 times:
X [ERROR] Unexpected end of file in JSON

../../package.json:1:0:
  1 │
    ╵ ^

The project builds and I've checked the package-lock.json, angular.json and package.json. I also looked in .gitignore, which is empty.
Anyone seen this before?

Check if there is a package.json in the parent directory of your project? I was reading this relevant comment on Github, maybe it helps you too. https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2404#issuecomment-793166114

Thank you, Dragos - there was an older project that I had open in the same folder - I deleted it and the server built!

Hey, glad to help!
